# How to implement Async behaviour in response to send email while response return in Java

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, executorservice

I am using spring application and we have a SOA architecture based on REST API. I have an API for example create user(http://myapp/api/createUser)

So now when a user is created we need to send an email to user right away.I did implement it but it wait for email method to send email and return success/failure, which consumes time.

Please how can i return success response from API right away by starting the e-mail part in thread and run in background and send mail to user. or if failure then logged in database.

Please suggest me the API or framework for that I dont want to implement Messaging Queue like Rabbit MQ or Active Queue.
Please share those implementation that do not create problem in live production server by spawning threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @Async in your email sending method.

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

Example:

```
@Async
public void sendNotificaitoin(User user) throws MailException {     
    javaMailSender.send(mail);
}
```

To enable @Async to work, use @EnableAsync in your configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SendingEmailAsyncApplication {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SendingEmailAsyncApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Use it like below:

```
        @RequestMapping("/signup-success")
        public String signupSuccess(){

            // create user 
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("Dan");
            user.setLastName("Vega");
            user.setEmailAddress("dan@clecares.org");

            // send a notification
            try {
                notificationService.sendNotificaitoin(user);
            }catch( Exception e ){
                // catch error
                logger.info("Error Sending Email: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return "Thank you for registering with us.";
        }
```

Comment: I think the response will not be received untill notificationService.sendNotificaitoin(user); is finished sending.
Do confirm? and send documentation if this is written somewhere.

Comment: nope, please check by running. sendNotificaitoin() is marked as async().

Comment: I tried to debug still the getting synchronous behaviors .I have put @Async to my method and as I am not using spring boot so added <task:annotation-driven/> in app-config.xml. Don't know where to add EnableAsync?. Can you help please.

Comment: Please tell me also in debugging does it show the asynchronous behavior ?

Comment: Check this example here: http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/01/13/asynchronous-method-invocation-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: Probably it's not obvious, but @Async method must be: 1) public; 2) not self-invocation (you should use another class). Reasons - proxy specialties. To check in debug mode you can use TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)